# Neo4j Finding path but without a certain node

Tags: path, neo4j, nodes, cypher

I am not very familiar with Neo4j because I just used it for several days.

But now I want to find path between two nodes

like path :　A & D

A -> B -> C -> D

A -> B -> E -> D

A -> C -> E -> D

and using "WHERE NOT" to eliminate Node B

so I will leave path A -> C -> E -> D

is there any way I can do this ?

Here is my Cypher:

```
MATCH (home { name:'Grove' }),(school { name:'Moulton' }),(Ann {name:'Ann'}),
p = ((home)-[*..4]->(school))
WHERE NOT ((home)-[]->(Ann))
RETURN p
```

It's not working for me

Comment: Hey, could you share some db information so we can test on it. such as these objects creation & relations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `NONE` predicate in the `WHERE` clause to filter out paths containing the `B` node. See http://console.neo4j.org/?id=hppthl for an example.

The cypher statement looks like this:

```
 MATCH p=(:Person { name:'A' })-[:KNOWS*..4]->(:Person { name:'D' }), 
       (without:Person { name:'B' }) 
 WHERE NONE (x IN nodes(p) WHERE x=without)
 RETURN p
```

Comment: Really Great helpful!!
Thanks a lot